# What to do if I turn 18 in a country I'm not a citizen of but living here with a 3 year visa and want to go back to my country?

Tags: visas, canadian-citizens, uk-residents

I am from Canada I came to the UK with my family for 3 years. During that time I turn 18 and I want to go back. Yes, I do have a passport. I am not going to live in the UK any more right when I turn 18. What am I supposed to then? I am a Canadian Citizen too.

What do I need to do?

Who am I supposed to contact?

How am I supposed to do all this too?

Comment: Do you have a passport?

Comment: I suppose buy a plane ticket, pack your bags, grab your passport and credit cards, and go. You should make arrangements for a place to stay when you arrive. Take a look at the various travel sites such as Kayak or Expedia. See this article http://traveltips.usatoday.com/travel-arrangements-13279.html  and this article https://www.trails.com/how_30345_do-travel-arrangements.html and see this article which has a list of resources to read near the end http://executivesecretary.com/an-admins-guide-to-travel-planning/

Comment: (1) Arrange for a passport, plane tickets, and a place to sleep when you get to Canada. (2) nobody in particular aside from those needed to complete #1. (3) this also depends on your specific arrangements in #1.

Comment: Turning 18 has no bearing on whether you'll be re-admitted to Canada.  There used to be an arcane rule where some people who acquired Canadian citizenship from their parents had to apply to retain it before they turned 28;  but these rules were repealed in 2009, and they wouldn't have applied to you anyhow.

Comment: Is this a question about the logistics of the travel? As such, it's easy, buy a plane ticket and board a plane back to Canada, done. You don't need anything else, since you're a citizen of Canada. If it is actually a question "how do I make a life-changing move to a new country (actually return to an old one), that is kind of beyond the scope of this SE. As it is, in either case, this is a question about moving from one country of residence to another, long term, which makes this question more fit for [expatriates.se] ...